# How and why can a Semaphore give out more permits than it was initialized with?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am reading the book Java Concurrency in Practice. In a section about `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`, the below lines are present in the book. It is a comment about its implementation of "virtual permit" objects

> The implementation has no actual permit objects, and `Semaphore` does
>   not associate dispensed permits with threads, so a permit acquired in 
>   one thread can be released from another thread. You can think of 
>   `acquire` as consuming a permit and `release` as creating one;  a
>   `Semaphore` is not limited to the number of permits it was created with.

Can somebody explain this? I am having trouble understanding this. If we create a pool of fixed size, we create a fixed number of "permits". From the above statement, it looks like the "permits" can keep growing. Why is it designed this way?

Comment: looks like just ornate phrase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of "handing out" permit objects, the implementation just has a counter. When a new permit is "created" the counter is increased, when a permit is "returned" the counter is decreased.

This makes for much better performance than creating actual objects all the time.

The tradeoff is that the Semaphore itself cannot detect certain kinds of programming errors (such as unauthorized permit cash-ins, or semaphore leaks). As the coder, you have to make sure to follow the rules on your own.

Comment: Does Java provide a different kind of semaphore which actually enforces the permit limit?  I just want release() to be a no-op when all the permits have already been released...  In a complex system with a lot of threads, it's not so easy to make sure that each thread always acquires and releases exactly one permit.

Comment: @Dasmowenator: I suppose you could roll your own on top of AtomicInteger. But that does not sound like a good approach. You should really make sure your locking code is logically correct. If you find the need to make release a no-op, that probably means that someone was releasing more locks than they should have. And that will break things that cannot be fixed by just ignoring some semaphore calls.

Comment: You could also use the traditional "synchronized" way of locking. Less flexible, but safe (no leaks, takes care of re-entrancy etc).

Comment: C# allows you to specify the max permits, why not in Java?

Answer (score 5):

> Can somebody explain this ?  From the above statement, it looks like the "permits" can keep growing.

A semaphore is a counter of permits. acquire is like decrement which waits rather than go below zero.  It has no upper limit.

> Why is it designed this way ?

Because its simple to do so.

Comment: No upper limit, wouldn't the upper limit be the number of permits?

Comment: The upper limit is the number of times release minus the number of times acquire has been called. You can call release any number of times.  There is an upper limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE in some implementations.

Comment: So how does one go about creating a solid semaphore with a maximum of 1 - regardless of how many times release is called ?

Comment: @slott for that I would use an AtomicBoolean.  You can `set(true)` to release and `compareAndSet(true, false)` to acquire.  This is non blocking.

Comment: Is it overkill to extend Semaphore and override release to do a drainPermits() ?

Answer (score 5):

I think that it means the times what we may require Semaphore as the times we released "extra" and plus the permits it created with.

Such as:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1); // one permit when initialize

s.acquire();
s.release();

s.release(); // "extra" release.
```

At this moment, this semaphore allows one permit originally and one "extra" permit

Comment: I'm confused by this for long; and looks crazy this is allowed

Comment: @LookIntoEast 3 years late but I just found this out too while messing around with Semaphores. Indeed this seems quite crazy lol!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in first post "*Semaphore is not limited to the number of permits it was created with*"

Every call to .release() API will increase the permit count by one. So Semaphores doesn't have a fixed permit size

Comment: can you explain the .release() working then? So, if i create a semaphore object with 0 then no thread can acquire permit from it? But if i call .release() on it first and then .acquire() in next line, it will allow a thread to acquire permit?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the last line " a Semaphore is not limited to the number of permits it was created with" is your source of confusion.

A semaphore when created is initialized with a fixed set of permits. This then becomes the maximum number of permits that the semaphore can simultaneuosly dispense at any time during the life time of that semaphore. You *cannot* dynamically increase this number except by re-initializing the semaphore .

The meaning if the quoted line ( from JCIP ) is this :  First , the semantics of how a semaphore works is not limited to the details of issuing and regaining a permit - this is manifested in the fact that any thread can that has access the semaphore can have a permit released ( even though this thread did not own the permit at the first place)

Second , you can dynamically reduce the maximum permits of a semaphore - by calling `reducePermits(int)` method.

Answer (score -1):

It is surprising to some of us.

You can easily subclass up a bounded semaphore.

```
/**
 * Terrible performance bounded semaphore.
 **/
 public class BoundedSemaphore extends Semaphore {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -570124236163243243L;
    final int bound;
    public BoundedSemaphore(int permits) {
        super(permits);
        bound=permits;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        super.acquire();
    }
    
    @Override
    synchronized public boolean tryAcquire() {
        return super.tryAcquire();
    }
    
    @Override
    synchronized public void release() {
        if( availablePermits()<bound){ 
            super.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    synchronized public void acquire(int count) throws InterruptedException {
        super.acquire(count);
    }
    
    @Override
    synchronized public boolean tryAcquire(int count) {
        return super.tryAcquire(count);
    }
    
    @Override
    synchronized public void release(int count) {
        if( availablePermits()<bound){ 
            super.release(bound-availablePermits());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: method is synchronized, only one thread is executing at a time.