# Is ArrayBlockingQueue in java implemented using semaphores?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, blockingqueue

Are BlockingQueues and specifically  ArrayBlockingQueues, implemented using semaphores in java? Do they use the same concept internally?

Comment: The JDK comes with the sources. Have you checked them out?

Comment: Please clarify your efforts. What you searched, what you found and what is the question that needs to be answered. What do you mean by the same concept? The concept of Semaphores?

Answer (score 0):

Different JDKs may have different implementations.
The OpenJDK does not use semaphores for the implementation of ArrayBlockingQueue. However you should specifically check the implementation you are interested as it is possible to develop an ArrayBlockingQueue using semaphores.

See the following link for different implementations of ArrayBlockingQueue.
[Grepcode:ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/search?query=ArrayBlockingQueue)

OpenJDK vesion 8u40-b25 uses Locks (ReentrantLocks actually) which is a different concept. You can see the sources in this link.
[ArrayBlockingQueue - OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue)

See this article on Locks VS Semaphores:
[Binary Semaphore vs a ReentrantLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683575/binary-semaphore-vs-a-reentrantlock)